# Python ggplot - how do I layer histograms

Tags: python, ggplot2

I have 3 histograms in Python ggplot that work just fine.  I would like to bring them together into one chart.  I've been told there is a way to add geom_histogram layers to your plot and pass it the data you want it to use but I can't figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from ggplot import *


subway_data_df = pd.read_csv('/home/brian/Dropbox/Data_Science_Course/Final Intro Data Science Project/turnstile_weather_v2.csv')



dry_days_df = subway_data_df.loc[subway_data_df['rain'] == 0].reset_index()

rainy_days_df = subway_data_df.loc[subway_data_df['rain'] == 1].reset_index()

very_rainy_days_df = subway_data_df.loc[subway_data_df['precipi'] > .10].reset_index()


print ggplot(very_rainy_days_df, aes(x = 'ENTRIESn_hourly')) + geom_histogram(binwidth=100, fill = 'green') + xlim(0, 8000) + ylim(0,6000)\
+ ggtitle('Subway Useage Under Heavy Rain Conditions') + xlab('Number of Entries per Hour') + ylab('Frequency')       


print ggplot(rainy_days_df, aes(x = 'ENTRIESn_hourly')) + geom_histogram(binwidth=100, fill = 'blue') + xlim(0, 8000) + ylim(0,6000)\
+ ggtitle('Subway Useage Under Rainy Conditions') + xlab('Number of Entries per Hour') + ylab('Frequency')       

print ggplot(dry_days_df, aes(x = 'ENTRIESn_hourly')) + geom_histogram(binwidth=100, fill = 'red') + xlim(0, 8000) + ylim(0,6000)\
+ ggtitle('Subway Useage Under Dry Conditions') + xlab('Nubmer of Entries per Hour') + ylab('Frequency')
```

Answer (score 0):

So to combine it all into one chart, you just have to convert the flags into one variable in one data frame. To do this we would use the `apply` method of dataframes. Based on my interpretation of the code you have provided above I have come up with the below:

```
def split_groups(row):
    if row['rain'] == 0:
        return 1
    elif row['precipi'] <= 0.1:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3

subway_data_df['rain_type'] = subway_data_df.apply(split_groups, axis=1)
```

With the plot function looking like this:

```
print ggplot(subway_data_df, aes(x = 'ENTRIESn_hourly', fill='rain_type')) + geom_histogram(binwidth=5000)
```

The plot would then look like the below:

[image]